# WPF WYSIWYG printing multiple pages

Tags: wpf, printing

I have 2 scenarios where I want to WYSIWYG print a usercontrol. In one scenario I have a GridView (by Telerik) that can span multiple pages in both X and Y directions. In the second scenario I have a TreeView (also by Telerik) that can span multiple pages in the Y direction. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Printing in WPF can be tough, I recommand using [PrintEngine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238135/WPF-Print-Engine-Part-I).

You may have to tweak it a bit, I know I did, but it's a very good head start.

You use it like this:

```
public static void PrintElement(FrameworkElement printMe)
{
    var suPrintVm = PrintControlFactory.Create(printMe);
    suPrintVm.ShowPrintPreview();
}
```

And then a preview shows up where you can specify printing details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me, it looks very promising. The RadTreeView shows up in the preview (still have to figure out how to print it contents rather than the sized treeview including scrollbars). The RadGridView doesn't show up though. The print preview has the correct size, but the pages are blank. Do you know what might be the problem?